# Separate a Javascript function to reuse it, how?

Tags: javascript, function

I see some javascript and try to implement the function seperated to reuse it.

This is the old code:

```
var ListRenderRenderWrapper = function(itemRenderResult, inCtx, tpl)
{
    var iStr = [];
    iStr.push('<li>');
    iStr.push(itemRenderResult);
    iStr.push('</li>');
    return iStr.join('');
}
```

And I would like to make something like this:

```
function wrapItems(itemRenderResult, inCtx, tpl)
{
    var iStr = [];
    iStr.push('<li>');
    iStr.push(itemRenderResult);
    iStr.push('</li>');
    return iStr.join('');
}

var ListRenderRenderWrapper = wrapItems(itemRenderResult, inCtx, tpl);
```

is this ok or do I need to do it in another way?

Comment: Have you tried it? If so, what happened?

Comment: Your last line would be `var ListRenderRenderWrapper = wrapItems;`, since you want it to be a function. But essentially yes.

Comment: To assign the function to `ListRenderRenderWrapper` so that you can later call `ListRenderRenderWrapper()`, you only need `var ListRenderRenderWrapper = wrapItems;`

Comment: I don't understand... you can already reuse the first function in your examples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to assign that function to a new variable so you can call it with a different name, simply do:

```
var ListRenderRenderWrapper = wrapItems;
```

The confusion may be coming from the fact that in JavaScript a function can be stored inside a variable and called as a function later.

This means that:

```
function thing() { /* code */ }
```

is the same as:

```
var thing = function() { /* code */ }
```

*(Aside: I know there are subtle differences with hoisting etc, but for the purposes of this example they are the same).*